# After installing KB2656351 and KB2600217 and restarting, Windows Update prompts me to download those updates again

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, .net-4.0

Resulting in an endless loop. What can I do?

This happened after I installed .net 4 framework for github.

Running win7 64bit

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: That's the solution that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repair the .Net framework 4.0 in the control panel:

Click `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Programs and Features`, select `Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile`, and click `Uninstall/Change`.

In the Maintenance screen that opens, choose `"Repair .NET Framework 4 Client Project to its original state"` and click Next. After the repair completes, click Finish. When you return to Windows Update, the .NET patches should install without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks, I intend do follow the steps when I'm ready to reboot my PC. BTW, I have to idea why my edit was rejected: "If this doesn't work, here are some additional ways you could resolve this issue: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-updates-repeatedly-offered-kb2656351-and/c7162758-c812-4522-a76a-1b4203984c5a http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/243441-forever-stuck-these-two-updates-kb265651-kb2600217.html http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Windows-7/Windows-Update-Always-Re-Install/td-p/332980"

Comment: only adding links is not recommend here. You have to write the steps here, maybe other sites are down or the links change, so you can find the information again.